# PHP creates 2 session files on next button click

Tags: php, apache

We have a static files deployed on Apache server configured with PHP. It supports search functionality with PHP code with search results on multiple pages. For the first time search works fine with 10 results on page. When I click on next button to see results on next page it says the session attribute is undefined. When I look into session.save_path it does creates 2 session file. One is when it is searched for first time (Not blank) and another when I click on next button (0 KB- blank always). 
In one environment where SSL/TLS is configured, this happens for https protocol. For http protocol, it is working fine.
In second environment where default Apache PHP SSL configuration is present, this happens for http protocol. For https protocol it is working fine.

My php code is as follows (Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.3)

```
    <?php
    require_once 'SearchContext.php';
    require_once 'NewSearchContext.php';
    session_start();
    $searchString = $_REQUEST["searchString"]; 

    if(isset($_REQUEST["action"]) && $_REQUEST["action"]!="")
    {
      $action = $_REQUEST["action"];
    }
    $hitsPerPage = $_REQUEST["hitsPerPage"];
    $protocol = 'http://';

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'|| 
   $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
        $protocol = 'https://';
    }

    if (isset($searchString)&&isset($hitsPerPage))
    {   
        $dispatcher = $protocol.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$context = new SearchContext($dispatcher, $searchString, $hitsPerPage);
$_SESSION["searchcontext"] =$context;

        echo $context->getNextPage();
    }
    else if ($_SESSION["searchcontext"]&&isset($action))
    {
        $context = $_SESSION["searchcontext"];
        if ($action == "next")
        {
            echo $context->getNextPage();
        }
        else if ($action == "prev")
        {
            echo $context->getPrevPage();
        }
     }

    ?>
```

SearchContext.php:

```
   <?php

 require_once 'SearchSettings.php';
 require_once SearchSettings::ZEND_PATH;
 require_once 'TextParser.php';

class SearchContext {

const XML_AMP = '&amp;';
const XML_APOS = '&apos;';
const XML_CR = '&#13;';
const XML_GT = '&gt;';
const XML_LT = '&lt;';
const XML_LF = '&#10;';
const XML_QUOT = '&quot;';
const XML_TAB = '&#9;';
const XML_DECLARATION = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

protected static $keyWords = array('Product', 'Descriptor', 'Process', 'Pattern',
                        'Type', 'Definition', 'Set', 'Asset', 'Considerations',  
                        'Category', 'Material', 'Grouping', 'Tool');

protected $indexPath;
protected $hitsPerPage;
protected $searchString;
protected $xsl;
protected $docBase;
protected $docFolder;
protected $searchResults;
protected $hitsCount;
protected $phpPageName;
protected $currentPage;
protected $dispatherPage;
protected $isCJKAnalyzer;

public function __construct($dispatherPage, $searchString, $hitsPerPage)
{
    if (isset($dispatherPage))
    {
        $this->dispatherPage = $dispatherPage;
    }
    $this->searchString = $searchString;
    $this->hitsPerPage = $hitsPerPage;

    $this->_initialize();
    $this->_doSearch();
}

private function _initialize()
{
    $this->indexPath = realpath('./index/');
    $this->xsl = realpath('./search_result.xsl');
    $version = file($this->indexPath."/version.txt");
    if (preg_match('/^CJKAnalyzer$/u', isset($version[1]) ? $version[1] : null))
    {
        $this->isCJKAnalyzer = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->isCJKAnalyzer = false;
    }
    $this->docFolder = explode('*',$version[0]);
    $this->docFolder = $this->docFolder[0];

    $protocol = 'http://';
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off'|| $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
        $protocol = 'https://';
    }
    $this->phpPageName = $protocol.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $this->docBase = substr($this->phpPageName, 0, strrpos($this->phpPageName, '/'));
    $this->docBase = substr($this->docBase, 0, strrpos($this->docBase, '/'));
}

private function _doSearch()
{
    $this->currentPage = -1;
    if ($this->_isInvalidSearchString($this->searchString))
    {
        $this->hitsCount = 0;
        return;
    }
    Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new TextAnalyzer($this->isCJKAnalyzer));
    Zend_Search_Lucene::setDefaultSearchField('contents');
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open($this->indexPath);
    $query = TextParser::parse($this->searchString, "UTF-8");
    $hits = $index->find($query);
    $this->hitsCount = count($hits);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->hitsCount; $i++)
    {
        $hit = $hits[$i];
        $document = $hit->getDocument();
        $url =  $document->getFieldValue('url');
        $title = $document->getFieldValue('title');
        $summary = $document->getFieldValue('summary');;
        $umaType = $document->getFieldValue('uma.type');
        if(strcasecmp($umaType, "udt")==0){
            $searchicon=$document->getFieldValue('searchicon');
            $this->searchResults[$i]['searchicon']=$searchicon;
        }
        $this->searchResults[$i]['url'] = $url;
        $this->searchResults[$i]['title'] = $title;
        $this->searchResults[$i]['summary'] = $summary;
        $this->searchResults[$i]['uma.type'] = $umaType;
    }
}

public function getPrevPage()
{
    $this->currentPage--;
    $result = $this->_getResults();
    return $result;
}

public function getNextPage()
{
    $this->currentPage++;
    $result = $this->_getResults();
    return $result;
}

private function _getResults()
{
    try {
        $initPageNumber = $this->currentPage * $this->hitsPerPage;
        $maxPageNumber = min($this->hitsCount, $initPageNumber + $this->hitsPerPage);
        $nextEnabled = ($this->hitsCount > ($initPageNumber + $this->hitsPerPage)) ? 'true' : 'false';
        $prevEnabled = ($this->currentPage > 0) ? 'true' : 'false';     
        $searchResultXML =  self::XML_DECLARATION.'<SearchResult'.
                            ' totalHits="'.$this->hitsCount.
                            '" initPageNum="'.(($initPageNumber > 0) ? $initPageNumber + 1 : (($this->hitsCount < 1) ? 0 : 1)).
                            '" maxPageNum="'.$maxPageNumber.
                            '" hitsPerPage="'.$this->hitsPerPage.
                            '" nextEnabled="'.$nextEnabled.
                            '" prevEnabled="'.$prevEnabled.
                            '" nextText="'.SearchSettings::NEXT_ACTION_TEXT.
                            '" prevText="'.SearchSettings::PREVIOUS_ACTION_TEXT.
                            '" imagePath="'.$this->docBase.'/search/images/'.
                            '" searchString="'.TextParser::_filterCharacter($this->searchString).
                            '" nextHref="'.$this->dispatherPage.'?action=next'.
                            '" prevHref="'.$this->dispatherPage.'?action=prev'.
                            '">';

        for($i = $initPageNumber; $i < $maxPageNumber; $i++)
        {
            $url =  $this->searchResults[$i]['url'];
            $title = $this->searchResults[$i]['title'];
            $summary = $this->searchResults[$i]['summary'];
            $umaType = $this->searchResults[$i]['uma.type'];

            $searchResultXML.= '<SearchHit';
            if (isset($url)) 
            {
                $fixedUrl = $this->docBase.substr($url, strpos($url, $this->docFolder)+ strlen($this->docFolder));
                $searchResultXML.= ' url="'.$this->urlEscape($fixedUrl).'"';
            }

            if (isset($title)) 
            {
                //$searchResultXML.= ' title="'.$title.'"';
                $searchResultXML.= ' title="'.$this->htmlEscape($title).'"';
            }

            if (isset($summary)) 
            {
                $searchResultXML.= ' summary="'.$this->htmlEscape($summary).'"';
            }

            if (isset($umaType)) 
            {
                // Here will be modified later
                if (strcasecmp($umaType, 'General_content') == 0)
                {
                    $searchResultXML.= ' icon="Other.gif"';
                }else if(strcasecmp($umaType, "udt")==0){
                    $shapeImage=$this->searchResults[$i]['searchicon'];
                    if(isset($shapeImage)){
                        $searchIcon="./../../".$shapeImage;
                        $searchResultXML.=' icon="'.$searchIcon.'"';
                    }else{
                        $searchResultXML.=' icon="Other.gif"';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $searchResultXML.= ' icon="'.$this->convertFirstLetterCase($umaType, self::$keyWords).'.gif"';
                }               
            }
            $searchResultXML.= '/>';
        }
        $searchResultXML.= '</SearchResult>';

        //echo htmlentities($searchResultXML);

        //  XML transform
        $processor = new XSLTProcessor;
        $xsl = new DOMDocument;
        $xsl->load($this->xsl);
        $xml = new DOMDocument;
        $xml->loadXML($searchResultXML);
        $processor ->importStyleSheet($xsl);
        $result = $processor ->transformToXML($xml);
        // echo htmlentities($result);
    }  catch(Exception $e) {
        $result = SearchSettings::SEARCH_FAILED;
    }

    return $result;
}

protected function urlEscape($url)
{
    $result = str_replace('\\', '/', $url);
    return $result;
}

protected function htmlEscape($content)
{
    $result = "";
    $len = strlen($content);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $ch = $content[$i];
        switch ($ch) {
        case '<':
            $result .= self::XML_LT;
            break;
        case '>':
            $result .= self::XML_GT;
            break;
        case '&':
            $result .= self::XML_AMP;
            break;
        case '"':
            $result .= self::XML_QUOT;
            break;
        case '\'':
            $result .= self::XML_APOS;
            break;
        case '\r':
            $result .= self::XML_CR;
            break;
        case '\n':
            $result .= self::XML_LF;
            break;
        default:
            $result .= $ch;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

protected function convertFirstLetterCase($str, $keyWords)
{
    $lstr = ucfirst(strtolower($str));
    foreach($keyWords as $keyWord)
    {
        $lstr = str_ireplace($keyWord, $keyWord, $lstr);
    }
    return $lstr;
}

private function _isInvalidSearchString($str)
{
    if (($str==null)||(trim($str)=='')||(iconv_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')==1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: can we see the code for `SearchContext.php` and `NewSearchContext.php`?

Comment: @treyBake: Added code for SearchContext.php

Comment: I suggest going through each required file - my guess is that there's another `session_start()` somewhere

Comment: @treyBake: I verified that another session_start() is not present in any other file. By the way, as faar as I know even if there is another session_start() present, it won't create new session and will simply say: Notice - A session has already been started - ignoring session_start()